# Is there a Twitter topic aggregator that goes beyond trends?

Tags: twitter

I'm looking for a Twitter service that does not just detect *keywords* (like the trending topics do), but instead deliver *stories* that are ranked by their popularity over a period of time.

Example: If I do a search for "car" it would not list all the tweets that contain `#car`, but instead, give me *current relevant stories* about car trade shows, new car parts, etc.

Comment: how would the service know beyond the hashtag that the 140 characters relate to car stories?

Comment: The same way Facebook knows how to group status updates of multiple people talking about a topic into one update. I guess a fair amount of algorithmic know how would have to go into such a service. Link introspection surely would help to gain further insight on a topic.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are two companies doing what I requested earlier.

- http://www.crimsonhexagon.com/
- http://www.massrelevance.com/

They rank and curate tweets, which is what I initially wanted. Unfortunately they seem to be very focused on companies.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is one thing you're looking for?

http://tweetlevel.edelman.com/

> TweetLevel is a purpose built tool for PR and marketing to help people
>   and brands use twitter effectively. It will help you navigate the
>   media cloverleaf to make your social media engagement successful.